# Why does this code compile on Coliru but not on Xcode?

Tags: c++, xcode, templates, abstract-class, crtp

I sometimes use the former as a testbed and then move code to my real project in XCode. That's not working for me in this case. The following code compiles and runs on Coliru (see cat /Archive2/48/70c3935989bffb/main.cpp) but not on XCode.

```
#include <cassert>

template <typename T, typename P>
class Permutation
{
public:

    virtual bool operator==(const P& other) const;
    // other member functions not listed here use the type T
};

template <typename T>
class SmallPermutation : public Permutation<T, SmallPermutation<T> >
{    
public:

    SmallPermutation(int i);    
    virtual bool operator==(const SmallPermutation& other) const;
    int code;
    // other member functions not listed here use the type T
};


template <typename T>
SmallPermutation<T>::SmallPermutation(int i)
{
    code = i;
}

template <typename T>
bool SmallPermutation<T>::operator==(const SmallPermutation& other)  const
{
    return code == other.code;
}

int main()
{    
    SmallPermutation<int> a(4);
    SmallPermutation<int> b(7);
    SmallPermutation<int> c(4);

    assert(a == c);
    assert(!(a == b));

    return 0;
}
```

Here is part of the error message from XCode (which I don't understand):

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"Permutation<int, SmallPermutation<int> >::operator==(SmallPermutation<int> const&) const", referenced from:
  vtable for Permutation<int, SmallPermutation<int> > in permutationTest.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Is there something nonstandard about the code? Are there build/compile/environment settings in XCode that I need to adjust?

Background: I have several (template) classes with the same interface and would like them all to inherit from an abstract class. The template stuff makes this task is a little harder. I used (possibly erroneously) a technique called CRTP (Curiously Recurring Template Pattern) to make it happen.

Answer (score 1):

If you declare a non-pure virtual function, like the `operator==` function in your `Permutation` class, then it needs to have a definition, you must provide a function body for the function.

The solution is to either make it pure:

```
virtual bool operator==(const P& other) const = 0;
```

Or to provide a dummy implementation:

```
virtual bool operator==(const P& other) const { return false; }
```

Comment: This simple adjustment fixed my build! I'm still wondering why the difference in behaviour in the two frameworks.